# React native: useState not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I'm new to react native and currently struggling with an infinite scroll listview. It's a calendar list that need to change depending on the selected company (given as prop). The thing is: the prop (and also the `myCompany` state are changed, but in the `_loadMoreAsync` method both `prop.company` as well as `myCompany` do hold their initial value.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import * as Api from '../api/api';
import InfiniteScrollView from 'react-native-infinite-scroll-view';

function CalenderFlatList(props: { company: any }) {
  const [myCompany, setMyCompany] = React.useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [canLoadMore, setCanLoadMore] = React.useState(true);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(undefined);

  let loading = false;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMyCompany(props.company);
  }, [props.company]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('set myCompany to ' + (myCompany ? myCompany.name : 'undefined'));
    _loadMoreAsync();
  }, [myCompany]);

  async function _loadMoreAsync() {
    if ( loading )
      return;

    loading = true;

    if ( myCompany == null ) {
      console.log('no company selected!');
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('use company: ' + myCompany.name);
    }

    Api.fetchCalendar(myCompany, startDate).then((result: any) => {
      // code is a little more complex here to keep the already fetched entries in the list...
      setData(result);

      // to above code also calculates the last day +1 for the next call
      setStartDate(lastDayPlusOne);

      loading = false;
    });
  }

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    // code to render the item
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderScrollComponent={props => <InfiniteScrollView {...props} />}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item: any) => '' + item.uid }
      canLoadMore={canLoadMore}
      onLoadMoreAsync={() => _loadMoreAsync() }
    />
  );
}
```

What I don't understand here is why `myCompany` is not updating at all in `_loadMoreAsync` while `startDate` updates correctly and loads exactly the next entries for the calendar.

After the prop `company` changes, I'd expect the following output:

> set myCompany to companyName
>
> use company companyName

But instead i get:

> set myCompany to companyName
>
> no company selected!

I tried to reduce the code a bit to strip it down to the most important parts. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: this is not making sense. If this is true, you can just pass the company into `_loadMoreAsync(company)`. But i don't think this can happen. Because you can move all algorithm to `React.useEffect`.

Comment: You are a little bit confused about on what is a state in react, I'm saying that because the propriety loading is managed in the wrong method. Maybe if you can reproduce the problem wi a minimum reproducible example, we can help to understand better your problem

Comment: @windmaomao that's right, if I move everything into `React.useEffect` it works like a charm. And it also works if I pass `company` to `_loadMoreAsync`. The thing is that I need to access `_loadMoreAsync` also from the outside of `React.useEffect`. Otherwise the onLoadMoreAsync property of FlatList would not have access. And so my example is not correct, because after a change of `props.company` I can manage to produce the right output, but if I call `_loadMoreAsync` from another place it still uses the initial value of `myCompany`.

Comment: I think the problem only occurs in the `onLoadMoreAsync` property of `FlatList`. Is it possible that this uses some sort of caching? If I replace it with `onLoadMoreAsync={() => { console.log(myCompany); }}` it only prints out the initial value but never updates on the current state of `myCompany`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping two nights over the problem I solved it by myself. The cause was an influence of another piece of code that used React.useCallback(). And since "useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed" (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) the code worked with the old (or initial) state of the variables.

After creating the whole page new from scratch I found this is the reason for that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Google for useEffect stale closure.

When the function is called from useEffect, it is called from a stale context - this is apparently a javascript feature :) So basically the behavior you are experiencing is expected and you need to find a way to work around it.

One way to go may be to add a (optional) parameter to _loadMoreAsync that you pass from useEffect. If this parameter is undefined (which it will be when called from other places), then use the value from state.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
<FlatList
    data={data}
    renderScrollComponent={props => <InfiniteScrollView {...props} />}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item: any) => '' + item.uid }
    canLoadMore={canLoadMore}
    onLoadMoreAsync={() => _loadMoreAsync() }
    extraData={myCompany}
 />
```

If your FlatList depends on a state variable, you need to pass that variable in to the extraData prop to trigger a re-rendering of your list. More info [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata)